# Хорошая практика передачи пропсов, React

Tags: reactjs

Является ли хорошей практикой прописывать каждый пропс и передавать его по отдельности? 
Пример, если передаем по отдельности:

```
const { filterPhoneSearch, purchasedPhones, totalPrice } = this.props
    return (
      <Search
        purchasedPhones={purchasedPhones}
        totalPrice={totalPrice}
        searchValue={searchValue}
       />
```

А можно:

```
return <Search { ...this.props } />
```

Как поступать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чтобы не заниматься передачей пропсов через всё приложение, обычно получается универсальнее и легче в дальнейшей поддержке сделать так:

предположим ваш компонент называется SearchLayout:

```
import SearchLayout ...
import Search ...

<SearchLayout searchBar={<Search ... />} />

// or
<SearchLayout><Search ... /></SearchLayout>
```

Далее, внутри SearchLayout вы можете его вывести компонент как есть (return props.searchBar) или через React.cloneElement - если нужно модифицировать его как то

фишки типа `<Search { ...this.props } />` без использования ts или flow обеспечат вам часы дебага в будущем, или другим членам комманды

Если хочется передавать пропсы (но опять же без статического анализатора это опасное занятие), можно сделать так:

```
type SearchLayoutProps = { SearchProps: Partial<SearchProps> } 

// in SearchLayout
<Search whatever="anything" {...this.props.SearchProps } />

// или так, смотря какая стоит задача 
<Search {...this.props.SearchProps } whatever="anything"  />
```